# Validate multiple file with same name validate in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

below are my form inputs :

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" multiple="true"></input>
<input type="file" name="image[]" multiple="true"></input>
```

and validation rules which i have used is :

```
'image' => 'required',
'image.*' => 'required',
```

I want to validate both the image file required But by above code only first image type is validating.

Comment: You have to use different name for both input. like `name="image1[]"` and `name="image2[]"`.

Comment: check out the official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: My array format is like this : image[0][image],  image[1][image] .

Comment: `<input type="file" name="image[1]" multiple="true"></input>
<input type="file" name="image[2]" multiple="true"></input>`

'image.*' => 'required'

Answer (score -1):

instead of

```
'image' => 'required',
'image.*' => 'required',
```

you could use

```
'image.*' => 'required',
```

this might solve your problem